# How to visualize small values in 3D bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d, bar3d

Can any one help me to find solutions for visualizing small values in the following 3D bar chart.

[image: click here to see the chart]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(10)

#data
time = [[148.64793017553907, 47.00162830693381, 1.3599472795213974, 1.0770502873829435, 0.2416407755443028, 0.051920437812805136],
        [100.7717864097111, 11.489065728868756, 0.5487183400562831, 0.12449462073189865, 0.15135425840105324, 0.030407779557364272],
        [10.223643741910418, 1.6037633759634835, 0.3846410546983991, 0.09999658720833912, 0.07089985779353546, 0.029794696399143727],
        [0.9271023046402703, 0.1371803828648158, 0.3223802804946899, 0.09767089911869589, 0.024286287171500026, 0.029627582005092024],
        [0.11088135128929497, 0.06808395726340152, 0.224113655090332, 0.08966402666909352, 0.022294637135096912, 0.029868837765284897]]

colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'y','m']
yticks = [1,2,3,4,5]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111 ,projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_yticks(yticks)
xs=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
for i in range(5):
    ax.bar(xs, time[i], zs=i+1, zdir='y', color=colors[i], alpha=0.8)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("3d.png")
plt.show()
```

I have tried to visualize data in 3d bar chart of matplotlib, but small values are not visible in the chart.

I am looking for solutions to make small values clearly represented in the chart.

Comment: Have you considered using a log scale for the z axis?

Comment: yes i used it, but it doesn't give the expected results.

Comment: `ax.set_zscale('symlog')`

Answer (score 0):

Log scaling has the issue that log is not finite for 0. You could try using a different sub-linear scaling, such as the square root (or the kth root for any k > 1). Then, you can set the z-tick labels so that they reflect this scaling. Here's an example using the 5th root (scalepower = 1/5).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np

# given the time array from the OP

scalepower = 1/5

colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'y','m']
yticks = [1,2,3,4,5]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111 ,projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_yticks(yticks)
xs=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
for i in range(5):
    ax.bar(xs, np.array(time[i])**scalepower, zs=i+1, zdir='y', color=colors[i], alpha=0.8)

plt.tight_layout()
    
def format_ticks(z, pos):
    return f'{z**scalepower:.2f}'

formatter = ticker.FuncFormatter(format_ticks)
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

plt.savefig("3d.png")
plt.show()
```

[image]